# Google Big Query Dataset Access group members list

Tags: google-bigquery

When we create a dataset in Google big query, by default that dataset is shared by the following access groups:
"project Owners", project Editors" "project Viewers".

Is it possible to get/know the members in those access groups or any specific big query API we can use to get the member's list in the Access groups.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable: Cloud User Accounts API. After that you can use the Users:list API call to obtain the list of users of a **project**.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/api/latest/users/list

For a **BigQuery dataset** you can use the API calls under Dataset:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#resource

access[]    list    [Optional] An array of objects that define dataset access for one or more entities. You can set this property when inserting or updating a dataset in order to control who is allowed to access the data. If unspecified at dataset creation time, BigQuery adds default dataset access for the following entities:

```
access.specialGroup: projectReaders; access.role: READER; 
access.specialGroup: projectWriters; access.role: WRITER; 
access.specialGroup: projectOwners; access.role: OWNER; 
access.userByEmail: [dataset creator email]; access.role: OWNER;
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe it is at project level but not dataset group level. Can we also get dataset access group members with the Cloud User Accounts API?

Answer (score 0):

To get roles/members for given **projectID** use (from Google Cloud Resource Manager APIs):

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/projectID:getIamPolicy
```

To get roles/members for given **datasetID** use (from BigQuery API):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectID/datasets/datasetID
```